# How can I use a PKCS12 ssl certificate with newer LWP?

Tags: perl, ssl, pkcs#12

I'm having difficulty getting a PKCS12 certificate to work using new LWP (6.x). Basically, this code works under perl5.8.8 and old [Crypt::SSLeay](http://metacpan.org/module/Crypt%3a%3aSSLeay) (version 0.57) and [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) (version 5.826):

```
local $ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = $sslPassword;
local $ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE} = $pkcs12_cert;
my $response = LWP::UserAgent->new->request(POST($url, Content => $content));
```

...but does not under perl5.14.2 and latest versions of Crypt::SSLeay 0.64) and LWP (6.03).

By doesn't work, I mean that I get an HTTP::Response object back like:

```
bless( {
     '_content' => 'Can\'t connect to host:port
',
     '_rc' => 500,
     '_headers' => bless( { 
                            'client-warning' => 'Internal response',
                            'client-date' => 'Thu, 27 Sep 2012 18:28:34 GMT',
                            'content-type' => 'text/plain'
                          }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
     '_msg' => 'Can\'t connect to host:port',
     '_request' => ...
)
```

I understand that much ssl-related code has changed in LWP lately; is PKCS12 support known to still work?  Should I be setting different variables/options in order to get the certificate and password to be picked up?

I've also tried passing this to LWP::UserAgent->new with no luck:

```
ssl_opts => {
    SSL_use_cert => 1,
    SSL_cert_file => $pkcs12_cert,
    SSL_passwd_cb => sub { $sslPassword },
}
```

---

Follow-up: I converted the PKCS12 cert to a PEM:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in my_pkcs12.p12 -out mycert.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in my_pkcs.p12 -out mykey.pem -nocerts
<passphrase entered>
```

and can use the new files via:

```
curl -k --cert mycert.pem --key mykey.pem --pass passphrase --cert-type PEM https://url
```

...and set these environment variables in the test script:

```
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = 'mycert.pem';
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE}  = 'mykey.pem';
```

...and *that* works as well under older LWP, and again does not work under new LWP.. so at least it is not something specific to PKCS12 certs at issue, but rather something more fundamental in how SSL handling has been changed internally.

Answer (score 3):

For PEM files, at least, this works with new LWP (it would seem that the environment variables are no longer recognized - perhaps Crypt::SSLeay is no longer being used by default?)

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    ssl_opts => {
        SSL_use_cert => 1,
        verify_hostname => 0,
        SSL_cert_file => 'mycert.pem',
        SSL_key_file => 'mypass.pem',
        SSL_passwd_cb => sub { $passphrase },
    },
);
```

These options are documented in [IO::Socket::SSL](http://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL); there is no mention of how to use a PKCS12 certificate here, so for that part of the problem at least, I am still searching.

Comment: Follow-follow up, a year later... I converted my PKCS12 cert into a different format and used that instead -- and chastized my vendor partner for choosing that format.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PKCS12 certs in strawberry perl 5.14.2 with WWW::Mechanize 1.72.

```
use Net::SSL ();
use WWW::Mechanize;
BEGIN {
    $ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = "Net::SSL";
    $ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
}
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE} = $pfxfile;
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = $pfxpass;
$ua = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$ua->cookie_jar({});
$ua->get($url);
```

The real pain was getting it to work with proxies.

Answer (score 0):

As of [LWP 6.02](https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.05/Changes#L87), LWP's handling of HTTPS was unbundled to [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps) which depends on uses [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL) unless that default is [explicitly overridden](http://blog.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html).

Assuming you did not add a `use Net::SSL` or override `$Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS` before loading `LWP::UserAgent`, it automatically picked `IO::Socket::SSL` which does not look at environment variables:

```
local $ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = $sslPassword;
local $ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE} = $pkcs12_cert;
```

If you do specifically override `$Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS` either via the environment or within you script, you will also need to to disable host verification, again either via the environment:

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
```

or via

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The (just released) version 1.988 of IO::Socket::SSL added transparent support for DER and PKCS#12 format, so it should be possible to give the PKCS#12 file simply in SSL_cert_file now.